# Typical directory structure for iOS application

Tags: ios

After creation of a new project under XCode I have the following directory structure:
* project
* projectTests
* project.xcodeproj

Do you usually nest third-party modules under the project session or under the root of application?

Comment: Just want to check what the best practices are. I am new to iOS development, but there should be some guidelines or standards on this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ibo, it doesn't matter.  Files in Xcode that appear to be in folders, are really just put in quasi-folders that Xcode creates In your project's XML.  If you actually took a look at the REAL folder (on your desktop) then you would see the files are out of order.  It doesn't matter at all.  It's your preference as to where things go.